# Sql update works in sql developer but doesnt work in php, why?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I´m trying to update an appointment element in my table and that works just fine, when I execute it in sql developer, but when I try to run that exact same update via php (I copy and pasted it...) it won´t update the element, but I dont get an error. So oci_execute() returns true, but nothing happens. How is that possible?
Here´s my code:

```
public function updateAppointment($sozVerNr, $newDate, $newTime, $oldDate, $oldTime){ 
    $sql = "UPDATE appointment Set date = '{$newDate}', time= '{$newTime}' Where appointment.date = '{$oldDate}' AND appointment.sozVerNr = '{$sozVerNr}' AND appointment.time = '{$oldTime}'";
    
    $statement = oci_parse($this->conn, $sql);
    $success = oci_execute($statement) && oci_commit($this->conn);
    oci_free_statement($statement);
    return $success;
}
```

What is happening here??

Comment: Are you sure there are any rows that meet the `WHERE` conditions?

Comment: You should use a prepared statement with bound parameters instead of substituting variables. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54500572/how-to-use-prepared-statements-and-bound-parameters-in-php-oci8

Comment: As I said it works on sql developer and I use the same parameters in php, so yes the there are row that meet the where conditions

Comment: What does `oci_num_rows($statement)` return?

Comment: this error: oci_num_rows(): supplied resource is not a valid oci8 statement resource

Comment: Do it before `oci_free_statement($statement)`

Comment: it returns 0...

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. I suspect there may be extra whitespace in the variables, causing them not to match, but that should affect the copy/paste to Developer, too.

Comment: Just for fun, try doing it with bound parameters.

Comment: I tried it and oci_num_rows($statement) still returns 0 :/

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the correct database? There's really no possible explanation other than the `WHERE` conditions not matching.

Comment: Try doing a query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM appointment WHERE appointment.date = '{$oldDate}' AND appointment.sozVerNr = '{$sozVerNr}' AND appointment.time = '{$oldTime}'` and printing the result.

Comment: Just to see you are connecting to the correct DB and if this is a test environment then UPDATE the table with  condition as "where rownum = 1 " and see if this works

Comment: I suspect you don't have a column in appointment called "date" so the bastardized code sample is useless. If you are compaing a date column to a string, there's a bunch of session parameters (date format and language) which can mess things up. As other commentators have said, you should use bound parameters